# Geometric Brownian Motion: Can Ito's Lemma use stochastic drift/diffusion coefficients

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Wikipedia's page on [Ito's
lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Motivation)
introduces random process $dX_{t}=\mu _{t}\,dt+\sigma _{t}\,dB_{t}$,
where $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are *deterministic*, and $B_t$ is a [Wiener
process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process).

Being a non-mathematician, I latched on to the the [informal
derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Informal_derivation)
of **Ito's lemma:**

$$
df =
\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial t}}+\mu _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}+{\frac {\sigma _{t}^{2}}{2}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}}\right)dt+\sigma _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}\,dB_{t}
$$

I squared this off with the section on [Geometric Brownian
motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Geometric_Brownian_motion)
(GBM), where

$$
dS_{t}=\sigma S_{t}\,dB_{t}+\mu S_{t}\,dt
$$

and $f(S_t)=\log(S_t)$.  It starts with

$$
df = f'(S_t) dS_t + \frac{1}{2} f''(S_t)(dS_t)^2
$$

and ends up with

$$
df = \sigma \,dB_{t}+\left(\mu -{\tfrac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right)\,dt
$$

If I slavishly start with Ito's lemma above
and calculate $df$ by precalculating
$\partial f/\partial t$, $\partial f/\partial x$, and $\partial^2 f /
\partial x^2$, I get the same result.  However, I have to make use of
the fact that $\sigma_t\triangleq\sigma S_t$ and $\mu_t\triangleq\mu S_t$.
Since $S_t$ is stochastic, so are $\sigma_t$ and $\mu_t$.  This violates the
condition stated above that they are deterministic.

Can someone please explain why this is consistent?  I come from a background of
engineering rather than math, so something intuitive would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deterministic is too strong of a requirement.
You only need $t \mapsto \sigma_t$ and $t \mapsto \mu_t$ to be [adapted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapted_process) to the Brownian motion.
Intuitively, what this means is that the processes are not able to "peek into future" values of $B$.

Comment: Thanks, parsiad.  I Googled "adapted process" and the notation and jargon were quite new to me (even the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapted_process)).  [This](https://www.acted.co.uk/forums/index.php?threads/measurable-stochastic-processes.10191) page helped.

Comment: @user2153235: I understand. I'm glad it was helpful. The Wikipedia page assumes knowledge of measure theory. However, the intuition required is just that the processes do not "peek into the future" (i.e., they depend only on past knowledge).